# How to add id to @Html.DisplayFor parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I looking for decision how to add a id to @Html.DisplayFor, that to this id I could tied jQuery method.

```
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
</dd>
```

Thanks for some advise.

Comment: Sorry ! It is unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: `DisplayFor()` just generates text, not a html element (add the `id` attribute to your `<dd>` element

Comment: @Shyju  I have a jQuery function and I have to tied a Price item at view, and that is why I have to add id to Price.

Comment: Depends on how your jQuery code is using the element with Id "Price". Is it reading the value attribute value or just innerhtml/text of the element ?

Comment: @Shyju yes, I reading the value and then have change it at function.

Comment: @ if I want to read the value of Price, would it held to add id to <dd> element?

Comment: check the view source of your page and you will understand the result of the `DisplayFor` helper method. You are free to add an id to any element in your DOM element. Make sure you use the correct methods to read it. (`val()` method for input elements)

Comment: `<dd id="Price">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)</dd> ` and you can read it like `var v=parseFloat($("#Price").text())` . Keep in mind that `parseFloat` will return `NaN` when the value cannot be converted to a numeric one

Comment: @Shyju thanks, it is an answer for me.I can vote for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DisplayFor` helper method simply renders the value of the expression you are passing to it. So in your case, let's say your `Price` property value is `235.34`, The markup rendered by razor will be

```
<dd>
  235.34
</dd>
```

If all you care about reading the value of the `Price` property, you may consider keeping the value inside a hidden form element.  You can use the `HiddenFor` helper method.

```
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
    @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.Price)
</dd>
```

This will render the below markup

```
<dd id="item">
    235.34
<input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" value="235.34" />
</dd>
```

You can see that now you have an input element with id `Price`. That means you can read the value in jQuery like

```
var v = $("#Price").val();
```

Another option is keeping the value in HTML5 data attributes.

```
<dd id="price" data-price="@Model.Price">
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
</dd>
```

and you can read it like

```
var v = $("#price").data("price");
```

Comment: exactly, what I wanted, but did not know how. Thank you!